# How to make a domain class that belongs to one of a number of possible classes in Grails

Tags: grails

I want to create a Comment class to allow my users to add comments to a number of different things.

```
class Comment {

    User author
    String text

    static belongsTo = [post:Post, user:User]

    static contraints= {
        post(nullable:true)
        user(nullable:true)
    }

}
```

When I try and create a comment object using a post and without a user, i get the error "Property [user] of class [class Comment] cannot be null".

What is the best way to create a class that can belong to one of a number of different classes?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a plugin like [commentable](http://grails.org/plugin/commentable).

However, if you want to roll your own solution then you need to understand that making something BelongTo another object makes it a required relationship. Thus it can't be null. Remove the belongs to and do a uni-directional one-to-many relationship. See the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html) on modeling relationships.